# Erlang: How to remove node from Mnesia cluster

Tags: erlang, schema, distributed, mnesia

I am writing a distributed mnesia application and use a schema.
When a new node joins the cluster, it is added to the mnesia schema by a rpc call (from the masternode which started the schema) which runs the following functions:

```
start_Mnesia(MasterNode) ->
    mnesia:start(),
    mnesia:change_config(extra_db_nodes, [MasterNode]),
    Tabs=mnesia:system_info(tables) -- [schema],
    [mnesia:add_table_copy(Tab, node(), ram_copies) || Tab <- Tabs].
```

When a node crashes or disconnects, the master node receives a `nodedown` event and the node should be removed from the cluster. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
I ended up with following solution:
TabList is a list of all tables in my schema which my node is using.

> mnesia:del_table_copy(TabList, Node)

Comment: why you want to remove this node? When it comes back up it will re-join mnesia cluster.

Comment: When a node fails, another (backup) node is started and will do his job. Thus, I need the old node (which went down) to leave the cluster and it should be setup clean when it joins again. (Then he will be a backup node until another node fails)

Comment: you got one answer - so I will not add anything. The thing is, I have impression that you may be misusing mnesia in this case. local tables will not be enough? Do you need the cluster?

Comment: Yes, I need the cluster because I am writing a distributed application and need to exchange information between different nodes.

Comment: Did you get this to work? How?

Comment: I just edited my solution. I used the suggested method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This should do what you want](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#del_table_copy-2). According to the documentations:

> del_table_copy(Tab, Node) -> {aborted, R} | {atomic, ok}
>
> Deletes the replica of table Tab at node Node. When the last replica
>   is deleted with this function, the table disappears entirely.
>
> This function can also be used to delete a replica of the table named
>   schema. The Mnesia node is then removed. Notice that Mnesia must be
>   stopped on the node first.